# NEsted Virtualization not working on Azure VM

Tags: azure, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to start a nested VM on Windows2016 VM deployed on azure ( Size used allows Nested Virtualization ) and after all guides followed I'm not sure what i could be missing since i Do have Hyper V installed:

Role manager:

[image]

Services:

[image]

Error when i try to start the VM:

```
Start-VM : 'sfm-azure-01' failed to start.
Failed to start the virtual machine 'sfm-azure-01' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.
'sfm-azure-01' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID BA61E565-9B2B-4180-B79D-FD3F16882314)
The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'sfm-azure-01' because one of the Hyper-V components is 
not running (Virtual machine ID BA61E565-9B2B-4180-B79D-FD3F16882314).
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-VM -Name sfm-azure-01
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-VM], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.StartVM
```

References used: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this script for enabling nest virtualisation.
It looks like it checks all the prerequisites.
https://github.com/charlieding/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/live/hyperv-tools/Nested

Comment: hi @balrob sorry for getting into this too late, but we didnt moved with that approach since we opted to other product. thanks for your feedback though

Answer (score 0):

When creating an Azure VM, select the correct machine SKU. The **CPUs with hyperthreading support** generally have nested virtualization.

You need to select a size with the nested virtualization support.

For example, you can use **Dv3 machines**. See the links for some sample supported VM sizes. Also, check the screenshot below.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv3-dsv3-series
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv4-dsv4-series
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/ddv4-ddsv4-series
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv5-dsv5-series
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/ddv5-ddsv5-series
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dasv5-dadsv5-series
- 

[image]

You can also test nested virtualization by installing Ubuntu with WSL.

```
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
```

After running the command, it will enable Windows Subsystem for Linux, and now you need to restart the VM. After that, it will proceed. From the programs, you will see Ubuntu.

When you run it, you should get an Ubuntu bash terminal. This will show that you have nested virtualization working.

If it does not work, you will get something like this:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
Press any key to continue...
```

Setting the WSL version to 1 for Ubuntu may solve your problem (for only running Ubuntu). Run the command in Powershell and try running Ubuntu again.

```
wsl --set-default-version 1
```

If you are using the right sizing of VM and still get the above issue, I suggest opening a support case in the Azure portal so that MS can help solve the problem.

**P.S.** I suggested testing with WSL because it gives a better troubleshooting error message.